# Jquery selectors not working on loaded elements with ajax

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to load some content from a php script using ajax and excute some functions when the loaded element are clicked

```
<div class="f-screen" id="fff"><div class="row">
            <div style="width: 230px;margin-right: 4.1%; margin-left: 1%">
                <center><a href="#"><h5>' . $row["name"] . '</h5>
                <img src="' . $row["avatar"] . '" class="profile-pic" style="width: 141px;"></a><br>
                <hr> ....
```

but when i tried to use element selector on the loaded element nothing seemed to happen this is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fff").click(function(){
    console.log("button clicked");
});
```

});

the same jquery code worked fine when i selected an element that i already placed in my html file but it didn't work on the loaded one

Comment: You need to add the event after the ajax runs, or use delegated method listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you are assigning the `click` handler to elements that do not yet exist. You need to use event delegation.

In this case, try using the jQuery `on` method:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#fff', function(){
        console.log("button clicked");
    });
});
```

This method assigns a listener to the `document` (which is ALWAYS present), and then matches the handler to the element `#FFF`.